# if else statement under nested loop in vue.js show the exact value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement, vuejs2, nested-loops

I'm trying to make a loop to show blog posts.  Inside the loop, I use another loop to fetch blog likes.  If the auth user liked a blog, then I want to show an unlike button, otherwise a like button.  But the main loop keeps showing 2 buttons instead of one when multiple users like that blog.

```html
<div class="post" v-show="blogs.length" v-for="blog in blogs" :key="blog.id">
  <span v-for="like in blog.likes" :key="like.id"> 
    <span v-if="blog.id === like.blog_id  && like.user_id === authUserId">
      <a href="#" class="link-black text-sm">
        <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down mr-1"></i> UnLike ({{blog.likes.length}}) 
      </a>
    </span>
    <span v-else>
      <a href="#" class="link-black text-sm">
        <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up mr-1"></i> Like ({{blog.likes.length}} )
      </a>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

[condition are not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9sQI.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Your question is a bit hard to read. If I understand correctly; Both "like" and "unlike" is shown at the same time, even tho you have if/else?

Comment: yes @SølveTornøe i just want to apply the condition which i ordered in v-if statement

Comment: I understand. At first glance, the code looks correct. It is hard for me to debug this just like this. Could you provide a simple example where this behaviour occurs via jsFiddle or built in stackOverflow code snippet? If not, an pseudo example of the data "blog" would help a lot.

Comment: first of all if statement worked under loop once but when looping again that time if statement are not working.may be for using nested loop.

Comment: You can try to add a unique key to each span (if/else spans) to see if that helps. Vue might re-use the elements for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an inner loop, test once per blog if the user liked it:

```html
<div class="post" v-show="blogs.length" v-for="blog in blogs" :key="blog.id">
  <span v-if="blog.likes.find(like => like.blog_id === blog.id && like.user_id === authUserId)">
    <a href="#" class="link-black text-sm">
      <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down mr-1"></i> UnLike ({{blog.likes.length}}) 
    </a>
  </span>
  <span v-else>
    <a href="#" class="link-black text-sm">
      <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up mr-1"></i> Like ({{blog.likes.length}})
    </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/9u7v15sk/)